# Call to a member function store() on null - laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I'm trying to upload an image though everytime I submit it's returning that the store() on null error. I've set the form to enctype="multipart/form-data" which hasn't helped.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Function inside the controller

```
public function store(Request $request){

  $file = $request->file('imgUpload1')->store('images');
  return back();

}
```

Form below:

```
<form action="/imgupload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  {{ csrf_field() }}
  <div class="form-group">
     <label for="imgUpload1">File input</label>
     <input type="file" id="imgUpload1">
  </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: <input type="file" id="imgUpload1"> has no name attribute

Comment: Well... that's stupid on my behalf. Thanks!

Comment: Not stupid it happens, fresh eyes are all that was needed :)

Comment: inside your input tag replace id with name like this <input type="file" name="imgUpload1">

Answer (score 33):

I had the same issue what I did to fix is in the opening form tag add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` that should fix it. Without it laravel would not understand the file.

like:

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="formName">
```

Answer (score 6):

The data is always fetched with name attribute which is missing in your form input

Change

```
<input type="file" id="imgUpload1">
```

to

```
<input type="file" id="imgUpload1" name = "imgUpload1">
```

and do some validation in the controller side like this

```
$val = Validator:make($request->all, [
    'imgUpload1' => 'required',
]);

if($val->fails()) {
   return redirect()->back()->with(['message' => 'No file received']);
}
else {
    $file = $request->file('imgUpload1')->store('images');
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

you need add this code in your controller

```
if ($request->file('imgUpload1') == null) {
    $file = "";
}else{
   $file = $request->file('imgUpload1')->store('images');  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you are getting error because your store function is not seeing the file from your request from the input tag so to fix this set the "name" just I have done below

```
<form action="/imgupload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  {{ csrf_field() }}
  <div class="form-group">
     <label for="imgUpload1">File input</label>
     <input type="file" id="imgUpload1" name="imgUpload1">
  </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check to see if the file exists before attempting to store it.

```php
if($request->hasFile('imgUpload1')){
   $file=$request->file('imgUpload1')->store('images');
}
```